# Sometimes Material UI onClick props is not working

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, responsive-design, material-ui

I Have created a function and passed it to onclick props of the material UI Icon, But it does not trigger the function all the time when I click on it.

It is only working sometimes or when click twice or thrice.

This is how I manage on click

```
                  <EditIcon
                    onClick={() => {
                      window.scrollTo({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
                      setOpen(true)
                      setCategory(row.categoryName)
                    }}
                  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried your code with a simple tasks editing project, your code seems to be working fine. Here is the code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-andras-nbw2q